# How to Jar and Zip Project?

Tags: ruby, buildr

How can I package a jar file (packaged via buildr) and script files into a zip file? The jar file is created as per the buildfile:

```
define "myapp" do
...
package(:jar)
...
end
```

I tried [Zip Task](http://buildr.apache.org/rdoc/classes/Buildr/ZipTask.html), but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
package(:zip).include(package(:jar), :path => "distrib")
```

Or you can define a subproject for the distrib, see this [example](https://github.com/intalio/wapama/blob/master/Buildfile).